# can't change user

Tags: linux, shell, users

I setup `vsftp` with my ftp users' home directory at `/var/www` but I realized, it wouldn't let em login by ftp, I tried to connect to `127.0.0.1`. So then i wanted to "try out" my ftp user on the shell but I get this:

```
reg@regDesktopHome:~$ whoami
reg
reg@regDesktopHome:~$ su - ftp
Password: 
reg@regDesktopHome:~$ whoami
reg
```

Why does `su` not let me change the current user I'm wondering?

Comment: You can do this with "shell-less" accounts by doing a "sudo -u ftp bash".  You won't get a login shell, but you will be user 'ftp' with its permissions.   That can be quite handy when you're trying to debug a script that runs in some service account, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot login to the accounts that do not have a shell associated to them.

```
$ getent passwd ftp
ftp:x:14:50:FTP User:/var/ftp:/sbin/nologin
```

Note that the shell is set to `/sbin/nologin`. This account is meant for the `vsftp` daemon to run under, it's not meant to be logged into.

**NOTE:** You can still do things as this user, just not get a shell. One method would be via `sudo`:

```
$ sudo -u ftp touch /tmp/afile
$ ls -l /tmp/afile 
-rw-r--r--. 1 ftp ftp 0 Feb 22 20:27 /tmp/afile
```

So you could `touch` a file to the directory `/var/www` to see if the user can write to this directory.

Comment: Here it looks like `ftp:x:121:131:ftp daemon,,,:/var/www/:/bin/false`

Comment: @cerr - that's another way to do the same thing. The shell is set to `/bin/false`.

Comment: yep, i realized, thx!